# Why is a one-Fe unit cell used in FeSe?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, unit-cell, brillouin-zone

The true unit cell of FeSe has two Fe atoms and two Se atoms. However, a smaller unit cell with only one Fe atom is often used in the literature. This smaller--and seemingly incorrect--unit cell, results in a larger Brillouin zone, referred to as the unfolded Brillouin zone. What is the purpose of this?

Clarification: I am interested in the quasi-2D Brillouin zone of the crystal shown below. The Se sites above and below the Fe plane are inequivalent, necessitating a larger (dashed line) unit cell, and a correspondingly smaller Brillouin zone. The solid line encloses only one Fe site, and results in a larger, so-called "unfolded" Brillouin zone. This seems incorrect, and I want to know why the literature conventionally shows both Brillouin zones.

[image]

Comment: I think that you need to clarify the question and maybe include a diagram of the structure you're talking about as well. FeSe apparently comes in at least three different phases with each phase having a different structure: an $\alpha$ phase, a $\beta$ phase, and something called an orthorhombic marcasite structure phase.

Comment: Indeed you need to clarify which precise phase you are talking about. And, of course, unfolding Brillouin zones is a fine thing to do if it helps you analyze a particular problem.

Comment: @Thomas, the smaller unit cell was used because it is simpler and easier to analyze. Physicists were hoping that the larger and more complicated unit cell is unnecessary.